# How can I populate my data using recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Please give solution that how can I populate data of my firebase database with recycler view!!

I attach a link below for my android code.

Pls answer

[Recycler view not populate any data on my screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42854357/7624598)

Comment: don't repeat same question again.

Comment: I'm voting this post to be marked as duplicate. Please don't use this kind of way to get our attention. If your question is answer-worthy, I'm sure it will get noticed. Or else, someone else may put a bounty on it to make it got answered faster (also, it has been only 3 day since you post that question)